# Enable Systemd User-Service globally

Tags: systemd

Simple task. I have a user service that is installed globally on the system (i.e. in a path like `/usr/lib/systemd/user`). I now want to enable this service for all users on the system (i.e. make it enabled by default. I don't care whether users can disable it for themselves again or not). I do know I can enable the service as user via `systemctl --user enable my.service` - but that obviously only activates the service for the current user.

Not shure if relevant, but this is how the corresponding unit file looks. I tested it and it works:

```
[Unit]
Description=My App
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myapp --systemd-log
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `systemctl --global enable`.

This will create a symlink in `/etc/systemd/user/default.target.wants`. Users will not be able to simply disable the unit, but they will still be able to edit (override) or completely mask it.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, thanks!